# Silverlight TextBlock not binding to MVVM, what have I missed?

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, silverlight-5.0

MainPage.xaml
`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Pathname, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Mode=OneWay}" />`

App.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
     <vm:InspectViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

ViewModel

```
private string _pathname = null;
public string Pathname
{
    get { return _pathname; }
    set
    {
        if (_pathname != value)
        {
            _pathname = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Pathname");
        }
    }
}

public void UpdatePathname(string path)
{
    Pathname = path;
}
```

MainPage CodeBehind

```
private void lazyNavTree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)  
{          
    InspectViewModel vm = new InspectViewModel();        
    var path = view.GetPath().ToArray();
    string pathname = null;
    // to figure out what the pathname is
    for (int i = 0; i < path.Count(); i++)
    {
        TreeList treeItem = (TreeList)path[i].Key;
        if (i == path.Count()-1)
            pathname = pathname + treeItem.Name;
        else
            pathname = pathname + treeItem.Name + " : ";
    }
    vm.UpdatePathname(pathname);
}
```

The bound TextBlock shows nothing, nada, zip. The pathname shource is changing correctly but nothing seems to happen when I fire the INotifyPropertyChanged event on change.

I am sure I'm missing something really obvious but I can't figure out what!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating 2 instances of your ViewModel:

- in App.xaml (in app resources, this is the instance which is bound to)
- in MainPage code-behind (`InspectViewModel vm = new InspectViewModel()`, this is the modified instance)

You should use single instance of you ViewModel, for example,

```
var vm = (InspectViewModel)Application.Current.Resources["ViewModel"];
```

instead of creating it in MainPage code-behind.

Comment: ... OF COURSE! Genius! I knew it was something obvious. Thank you, problem solved...

Answer (score 2):

It's because you create an instance from your viewmodel every times in the lazyNavTree_SelectedItemChanged. You should use only one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just missed the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) in your binding, try;

```
Text="{Binding Path=Pathname, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Mode=OneWay}"
```

EDIT: Apparently this was not the problem, but keeping this answer since xhedgepigx provided a useful link as a comment below.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not it. I have tried it to make sure (and still no reaction from my TextBlock) but you don't always need to include 'Path=' [info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189022(v=vs.95).aspx) . Thanks

Comment: In that case, I can confirm that the 'Path=' is optional.